# ¿Por qué Selenium en Eclipse no abre la url que le indico?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, test, junit

tengo este código y al ejecutarlo eclipse abre la ventana de chrome pero no abre la url que le paso

```
package No.Importa;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class login1 {
    private WebDriver driver;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/test/resources/driver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void AccesNul() {
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

y en la consola sal esto

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c11e8cfe3078709382934e3916914-refs/branch-heads/5615@{#936}) on port 2171
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
abr 17, 2023 11:07:58 A.?M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Comment: Sugerencia: acostúmbrate a indicar la versión de las cosas que estás usando. Puede ser relevante a tu problema :)

Answer (score 1):

Eso significa que hay que decirle que permita cargar orígenes remotos (por defecto no está habilitado. En ciertas versiones de Selenium se arregla añadiendo opciones de ejecución del driver:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/test/resources/driver/chromedriver.exe");
        // Instancia de ChromeOptions para añadir opciones de arranque
        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        opt.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

        // ... puedes incluir cosas que estás intentando hacer más adelante...
        opt.addArguments("start-maximized");

        // Luego sí instancias el driver usando las opciones
        driver=new ChromeDriver(opt);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

    }
```

En otras, desde 4.8.2, Selenium incluye estas opciones automágicamente. Entonces, sólo se necesita actualizar la versión de Selenium que se está usando.

Más info: [aquí](https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/xL5-13_qGaA)

Answer (score 1):

Hola el error se debe a un problema que ultimamente esta pasando en las nuevas versiones de driver para chrome, si utilizas el siguiente codigo se arregla:

```
   ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            chromeOptions.addArguments(new String[] { "--disablenotifications"});
            chromeOptions.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Replicando el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.